How to hide sidebar menu in SharePoint?
This menu
Hello,
I need to hide this menu in SharePoint, is there any way to do it?
The reason for this is to make the presentation 'childproof' and to limit user access as much as possible. I want to direct users only on important things, and to avoid them clicking on this things.
I have no idea how to do it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You could inject the following css to hide the left nav bar
nav[role='navigation'] {
    display: none !important;
}
div[class^='searchBox_'] {
    display: none !important;
}
div[class^='pageContainer_'] {
    left: 0 !important;
} 

If you want to insert the code, you could use sharepoint extension
https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-add-js-css-ref
